# how validate if record not found on database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how make sure if record not found when sql query using where not get the result.

i use this source and work for display record if record found, but i don't know how use "if then else" for change the "while"

```
Sub usercheck()
    'Prepare Connection and Query
    dbconn = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=user_team;Uid=root;Pwd=")


    strQuery = "SELECT * " & _
               "FROM tb_team_user WHERE user_ip = '" & lip.Text & "'"

    SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbconn)

    'OPEN THE DB AND KICKOFF THE QUERY
    dbconn.Open()

    DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

    While DR.Read
        tbteam.Text = DR.Item("user_team")
    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: if there are no records, then Read will return false, and the loop will end. If you need to know if the loop was entered, set a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your while loop, you can add an if statement to see if there are any rows returned:

```
If DR.HasRows Then
    ' There was at least 1 row returned
Else
    ' There were no rows returned
End If
```